# error C2371: 'DATE' : redefinition; different basic types

Tags: visual-c++

```
class DATE    
{ 
    public:
        void extend_date(int,int,int,int );
        int  diff(int, int, int, int, int, int);
        int day,mon,year;    
};      

void DATE ::extend_date(int d1, int m1, int y1, int days)
{
    ... 
}

int DATE :: diff(int d1, int m1, int y1, int d2, int m2, int y2)
{
    ...
}
```

I have an error is Class DATE

> Redefinition; different basic type

Anyone please help me?

Comment: Most likely, the problem is that Windows headers already define [a type named `DATE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/82ab7w69.aspx). Consider using a different name for your class.

Comment: Yes its solved thank you .

Comment: zak and @IgorTandetnik: Please answer and accept an answer.